# How do you direct the user to a certain div and also send a GET request at the same time?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use `header()` in PHP so it will send a GET request, and also redirect the user to a certain div ID, and originally the code I came up with was this:

```
header("Location: ?load=10#divName");
```

However, that gave a 500 error code, due to "redirecting me too many times".

I then tried doing something like this:

```
header("Location: #divName?load=10");
```

However, this just completely ignored the GET request, which makes sense, since it thinks it's part of the div ID.
Should I just give up and try using a POST request instead, or is there a way around this? Thanks!

***Note:*** I only am using `header()` for tests, otherwise, it is connected to an `<a>` tag.

***P.S.*** If you are wondering what I'm trying to do over here, when you click a button, it sends a request to load more blog posts, and then it directs the user to the last blog post in the list that was just loaded. I changed the div ID for less confusion. Please let me know if there is a better way around this, I'm sure there is!

Comment: the error "too many redirects" is directly tied to your usage of `header()` (page that redirects onto itself, etc), no real surprise there I guess. Can you clarify your question please ? Not really sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Before `header()`, you need to check that it's already redirected or not. Because it redirects, again and again, your page whenever page comes to this line.

Comment: You wanted to load the last blog post to a div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First using a header tag, you need to use the full URI if you want to redirect to somewhere. I recommend using the global `$_SERVER` for it. [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Second, the thing that you want to do is achievable using javascript and ajax, instead of php. I recommend you research [the ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to see some examples.

But mainly to fix the main problem of "redirecting me too many times", check if you are looping something that can callback the header function more than once.

Comment: Yup, you were right, the redirecting was because that it was continuing to use `header()` every single time the page loaded, I just removed the `header()` and used `<a>` only. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm happy that I could help :)